# Dynamic URL on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

I'm using Laravel for my web app.

On each of the rows of my "countries" table I have an "edit" button which opens up a modal and fills the textarea with the existing name of the country. This textarea can be edited and updated in the database.

This is the partial code of my modal:

```
{!! Form::model($country, [
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'url' => ['country', 'lblCountryId'],
    'class' => 'form-horizontal'
]) !!}

// some more code

// and the edit button for each row
<td>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" 
         data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"
         data-id=" {{ $item->id }}"
         data-name="{{ $item->name }}">
         <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>
</td>
```

When the modal shows, I manupulate the value of the textfield with folloring JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#editModal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
        $("#lblCountryId").html($(e.relatedTarget).data('id'));
        document.getElementById("txtCountryName").value = $(e.relatedTarget).data('name');
    });
});
```

With that same script I want to edit the URL to which the form is posting, but JS does not seem to like that.

Is there any way I can change the URL of the form dynamically according to which row I clicked on?

Comment: Show the code where you change the form target url.

Comment: Tried "shown.bs.modal" instead of "show.bs.modal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of the previuous answers I was able to solve it this way:

In my form:

```
{!! Form::model($country, [
      'method' => 'PATCH',
      'class' => 'form-horizontal',
      'name' => 'myEditForm'
]) !!}

<td>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" 
         data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"
         data-id=" {{ $item->id }}"
         data-name="{{ $item->name }}">
         <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>
</td>
```

and in my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#editModal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
        document.getElementById("txtCountryName").value = $(e.relatedTarget).data('name');
        document.myEditForm.action = "{{ url('country') }}" + '/' + $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to this :

```
{!! Form::model($country, [
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'class' => 'form-horizontal',
    'id' => 'myForm'
]) !!}
```

And your script loke this :

```
$(function () {
    $('#editModal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
        var url = "{!! route('country', ':_data_id' ) !!}";
        $('#myForm').attr('action', url.replace( ':_data_id', e.relatedTarget.data('id') ) );
        document.getElementById("txtCountryName").value = $(e.relatedTarget).data('name');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks good.
I'm getting some problems though. Laravel does not seems to like the 
`var url = "{!! route('country', ':_data_id' ) !!}"; ` -> Route [country] not defined
If I change it to `var url = "{!! route('country.edit', ':_data_id' ) !!}";` which exists, the modal just does not show at all.

Comment: Try changing on("show.bs.modal", function (e) to on("shown.bs.modal", function (e), let me know your country.edit route..

Comment: That way the modal shows, but display the same "name" regardless of on which row I click the edit button.